# How to fix "Too many request" issue in xamarin forms on API call?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

As i have created simple application in xamarin forms using Web API for getting the data from database.
HttpClient is used to request the web API. Sometimes httpclient is returned response as "Too many request".
I could not fix this issue. Please let me know if you know about this.

Comment: is throttling enabled on the web api?

Comment: Do you happen to dispose the HttpClient?

Comment: @jason No, i am not enabled throttling.

Comment: Are you sending lots of requests at the same time?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, i have sending a multiple request at same time. But request sending as an asyncronus

Comment: The error comes from your API right? Then you should improve the ability of your backend to handle those requests or reduce the amount of requests at the same time.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes , the error comes when request API from xamarin forms. using below code for request API,                                                                               httpclient.GetAsync(uri); but  i got response as too many request

Comment: Yes, I know. As I said in the last comment, you should improve the ability of your backend to handle those requests or reduce the amount of requests at the same time.